# Passing CSS Styles to child HTML elements through Attribute Directives

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I am trying to send a list of styles to the child components be passed through the Attribute Directives.
For Example:

```
<div [mystyles]>
   <p>.....</p>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Through attribute directives I am able to modify the parent div 's css I am using.But want the [mystyles] to modify its child elements p and div .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngStyle directive in child component.

In your parent component you cam pass (via @input directive) the style you want to your child component, then the child component can use it inside your html.

Here a sample implementation.

**Parent.ts**

```
myStyles = {
   'background-color': 'blue',
}
```

**Parent.html**

```
<child-component-selector [parentStyle] = myStyles>
```

**Child.ts**

```
@Input() parentStyle: any;
```

**Child.html**

```
<p [ngStyle]="parentStyle">
   ...
</p>
```

[Here](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/) a little guide on how to use ngStyle

Edit:

You can compose in parent the myClasses variable that replace myStyles in this way:

```
myClasses = {
  "class-name-1": {
    "background-color": "blue"
  },
  "class-name-2": {
    "background-color": "yellow"
  },
  "class-name-3": {
    "background-color": "lime"
  }
}
```

And then use the classes in child element in this way:

```
<p [ngStyle]="parentStyle.class-name-1">
   ...
</p>
<div [ngStyle]="parentStyle.class-name-2">
   ...
</div>
```

(parentStyle var have the name you specify after @Input() directive, as in the previous example)

As you can see only one input is needed for pass several classes, it only depends to the input variable you pass to the child.

Comment: What if I wanted to pass multiple css classes to different child elements using single directive ?

Comment: It depends on what result you want to achieve, myStyle can be an array of objects or can be a more complex object that contain all the classes you need.
You can compose your complex object in parent component and then split it in child then use retrieved classes inside child html.
You can pass any kind of data in @Input directive.

Comment: And every child have his own input, so you can pass the same myStyle to several child.
But i need more info from you about your project if you need deeper answer,

Comment: i need to pass styles to the child component's individual HTML elements(like span tag or div tag) .i want to do this without getting input for each class since i am using the child component for several other scenarios.I need to bundle up the classes that need to be passed inside a single directive like <directive myclasses><directive> where myclasses will have have several classes of child components HTML